# Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 - second monitor resolution options

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo Pro 2 with screen resolution of 3200x1600. Will this support a 4k ultra resolution monitor?  Looking for a higher resolution than 1920x1080?

Answer (score 3):

So the Intel HD 4400 graphics on the Yoga 2 Pro are capable of driving the internal display at 3200 x 1800 x 32-bit @ 60Hz, and also the external display at 2560 x 1440 x 32-bit @ 60Hz via HDMI.

By reading other forum posts, a user posted regards to using a 4K monitor with a Yoga Pro 2.

*First of all, for those concerned about using this laptop with a 4K monitor, it works out of the box with no issues with a $2 microHDMI->standard HDMI adapter. The only drawback of using a 4K resolution is that the refresh rate is limited to 29Hz/30Hz which for me is a bit sluggish. There is no way around this limitation with any driver tweaks as far as I could tell. The Intel Broadwell Core-M simply does not have the capability of driving a 4K panel faster.*

I believe the slow 4K refresh rate is because the Yoga 2 Pro uses HDMI 1.4, which isn't capable of running 4K at 60Hz, but rather only 24Hz. I guess the user was able to achieve a bit higher refresh rate. You need a DisplayPort or HDMI 2.0 to run 4K at 60Hz.